# Waiting in Stage n with 0 in Pyspark Mllib code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib

I run a code on python. It is about Spark Mllib algprithms. The output gives stages like this.

```
[Stage 20:>            (0 + 32) / 32]
[Stage 20:>            (0 + 32) / 32]
[Stage 20:>            (0 + 32) / 32]
[Stage 20:>            (0 + 32) / 32]
[Stage 20:>            (0 + 32) / 32]
[Stage 20:>            (0 + 32) / 32]
...
[Stage 20:============>(31 + 1) / 32]
```

but it spends too much time in [Stage 20:>            (0 + 32) / 32]. Stage is (0+32) very long time. Is there any problem or is it normal? I tried same code with small data without problem. But with big size data it is like this. My computer is multiprocess (16 cores). Should I add a setting about parallelization or pyspark does it automatically?

Comment: can you check spark UI? see this particular stage. may be your data got skewed

Comment: how can i check spark ui? I use eclipse. Should i run code on anaconda jupyter?

Comment: run in debug mode, put a breakpoint and check `http://localhost:4040` in any web browser